# what should be the value of the "input_lenghts" in "forward function" in encoder rnn in seq2seq model

Tags: chatbot, recurrent-neural-network, seq2seq, nlp-question-answering, sequence-to-sequence

i'm training an encoder rnn for sequence to sequence model with batches of 10 sentences .
every batches have 10 sentences.
and every sentences have 60 words.

[image: my encoder rnn code]

in the encoder network of the seq2seq model what should be the value of the "input_lenghts" ?

it should be the number of words in each sentence [60] ? or
it should be the number of sentences in each batch [10] ?